# System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() method with progress bar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am reading a large text file in vb.net using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextFileURL). Since the process takes a few seconds to finish, would there be a possibility to use a progress bar?
.
`RawFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextFileURL)`
`lines = RawFile.ToList`
`If arg = "" Then MsgBox("IMPORTER IS DONE")`
.
There is no loop or anything that could be used to update the value of the progress bar. Any thoughts or workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use  a `For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(TextFileURL) / Next`  aproach

Comment: The problem is that even with _File.ReadLines_ you need to know the number of lines present if you want to use a precise progress bar. To get this information you should read two times the file so it will be counterproductive. You could use a progress bar with the marquee style (are we talking about winforms progress bar right?) but this will be just an indicator of the process running

Comment: @Steve Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reads a pretty big .TXT file line by line and reports progress:

Code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog

        dialog.Filter = "Text|*.txt"

        Dim result = dialog.ShowDialog()

        If result <> DialogResult.OK Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim stream = File.OpenRead(dialog.FileName)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)

        Dim percentage As Integer

        While True

            Dim line As String = Await reader.ReadLineAsync()

            If line Is Nothing Then
                Exit While
            End If

            ' TODO do something with your line

            Dim percentD As Double = 1D / stream.Length * stream.Position * 100D
            Dim percentI As Integer = Math.Floor(percentD)

            If percentI > percentage Then
                ProgressBar1.Value = percentI
                percentage = percentI
            End If
        End While
        Await stream.DisposeAsync()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Result:

[image]

Notes:

- this puts a burden on the stream as ultimately reading a line is small data

  - try using a buffered stream to reduce pressure
- notice that I only report when integer percentage is greater than previous

  - you'd overwhelm UI when updating the progress bar otherwise
- there is trivial async usage, you may want to improve that overall
- the progress bar doesn't exactly reach 100%, I let you fix that, it's pretty EZ to do

Comment: thanks for this. what does the D refer to in the percentD?

Comment: Because you need a non-integer for computing a precise percentage.

Comment: you used D with the percentD. What does D represent?

Comment: D for double, I for integer

Comment: I am referring to the 1D in the equation: percentD = 1D / stream.Length * stream.Position * 100D

Comment: It's VB syntax for double, you must do that else percentage will be wrong, check that with your calculator, it'll work in scientific mode but fail in programmer mode which uses integers.

Comment: Ok, basically you're saying percentD is the proportion of the file that has been read so far. Correct? If that is the case, how do you link it to the value of the progress bar in a way that we reach 100% by the end of the file? Sorry but progress bars are new to me. Cheers.

Comment: It's the accurate progress, then below I make it floor before comparing to previous progress because otherwise there would be as many updates as there are lines and that would kill UI responsiveness, I update every 1%. And yes, it's expected that progress bar max is 100. Just play with it in your debugger, you'll quickly realize that if you remove any of that, the behavior will degrade.

Comment: Thanks mate, what you want to do next is Task.Run with cancel token so it's neatly running in the background and cancellable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines`
as [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-6.0#definition) said, when you are working with very large files, `ReadLines` can be more efficient:

```
Dim lstOflines as List(Of String)
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(TextFileURL)

    lstOflines.Add(line)

Next line
```

For get the total number of lines, you can make a guess based on file Size instead processing two times the file

- *Code for getting filesize: (use before start processing)*
- 

```
 Dim myFile As New FileInfo(TextFileURL)
 Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length
```

Comment: @aybe File.ReadLines doesn't read all lines in _one go_ See the remarks section on the link provided in the answer. Has been specifically added to the File class to allow _enumeration_ of the lines.

Comment: @aybe read the documentation for ReadLines that I linked, Is a little Different from Read*ALL*Lines

Comment: You're right, sorry, I'm tired, it's late...

Comment: So yeah, even though ReadLines is better than ReadAllLines, you still can't report progress because you can't know in advance how many lines there are. Look at my answer, using a stream reader it's actually possible to report a percentage without needing at all to know the number of lines.

Comment: @aybe nice use of stream position

Comment: Thanks mate and sorry for the confusion! 